Facebook Login for Business returns blank popup window
I'm trying to set up the FB for business login on my facebook app (reviewed and validated).
I'm using laravel php callback. it works with users logged into facebook that have admin role on my app.
return Socialite::driver('facebook')
            ->scopes($scopes)
            ->redirect();
I works fine with users that are admin of my app, but i get a blank popup login page when I use any other users
Can anybody help on this?
inspecting the browser console it shows this error
c7bTB9A8MMc.js?_nc_x=d7ylh6LA-3y:69
ErrorUtils caught an error:
Minified invariant #21945;
